# 404 File Not Found Error while trying to download an EXISTING file

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-io

I am trying to make a form using CI.
Some text data is inserted into the DB and a file is stored into a folder like `/upload/books/12/some_book.zip`.

`upload` folder is located next to `application` folder of CodeIgniter. There are a few more folders containing accessible files inside.

```
c:\laragon\www\my_ci_project
```

My folder hierarchy is as follows:

```
my_ci_project
├─application
├─system
├─inc
├─includes
├─upload
  └─books
    ├─10
    ├─11
    └─12
      └─some_book.zip
```

My test url on local server is `http://my_ci_project.test/`

Everything works fine. I can see the file that resides in that folder using FTP client. But when I try to download the file **clicking** its link lie

```
<a href="http://my_ci_project.test/upload/books/12/some_book.zip">download here</a>
```

the browser returns 404 error.

Strange but

If I type

```
http://my_ci_project.test/upload/books/12/some_book.zip
```

in the browser's address bar **manually**, it downloads the file.

It also does not download file on my local server.

The file's CHMOD is  644 and the folders' are 755.

I have tried to use CI's download helper.

```
force_download($path_to_file);
```

I get totally blank page.

I've tried to understand that the file is really where it is called.

```
$file_exists = file_exists(base_url().'upload/books/12/some_book.zip');
```

returns `FALSE`.

Comment: Presumably the URL you used isn't actually the URL of the file. Or that folder is not accessible by HTTP through the webserver, i.e. it's not within the web root, or some routing engine's rules make it inaccessible, something like that. We can't be sure - we don't know your webserver and application setup, or the URL you actually used. A [mre] of the issue would be helpful.

Comment: Most likely your servers routing rules are preventing direct access to the file. You can make your own route in CI to serve up files.

Comment: I've ran into this problem myself as well when trying to retrieve an uploaded image. For me, the solution was to make sure I wrote something along the lines of  `_FCPATH_ . $path_to_file`;  Can you confirm that this does not help?  Edit: Ah, I missed out on the info regarding the direct access attempt o the file, never mind!

Comment: `if I type http://my_ci_project.test/upload/books/12/some_book.zip
in the browser's address bar it downloads.`...ok, but this contradicts what you say earlier in the question, when you told us that accessing the exact same URL returns a 404. It can't be doing both at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>It is because of mime types I guess.</strike>

After a short search I've noticed that I should tell the browser what kind of file it is.

```
public function download($file_path)
{
    //$file_path = base_url() . 'upload/books/12/some_book.zip';
    $file_contents = file_get_contents( $file_path );

    force_download($file_path, $file_contents);   
}
```

It is working now.

Comment: This code doesn't set a MIME type. What you're doing here is giving it a file name to provide to the browser, and also the data which is to be downloaded (i.e. the content of the file). As per https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/download_helper.html, there is a 3rd parameter you can pass to force_download relating to telling it to set a specific MIME type based on the file extension, but you're not setting that option here and its default value is `false`. So your code may be working, but your description of why it's working is inaccurate.

Comment: P.S. I assume that when you used `force_download($path_to_file);`, it failed because it couldn't read whatever path $path_to_file contained, for some reason (because as those docs, say, if you don't supply the $data argument, it tries to read the file content from the path given, instead).